# Java Web App in Phusion Passenger Server

Tags: java, spring, passenger

I have requirement where I need to run a java web app with Phusion Passenger Server.

I couldn't find anything states that it's possible. 
I am currently running the application in Tomcat server.

Tech Stack:

> HTML, CSS, AngularJS, Java, Spring MVC, Spring Security,
>   MySQL/Oracle/MSSQL

Is this a possible case?

Comment: You do realize that this is for Python, Ruby and Node right? It's the first thing you see when you search for this on Google.

Comment: Yes @Eldelshell. I did search in Google before posting the question here. But I had a requirement and I thought somebody would have used the passenger server in the way which I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passenger developer here.

Java support (or more correctly: support for apps written in any programming language) is still a work in progress. According to our current roadmap we may have something before mid-2017. Unfortunately we cannot help you now but we recognize the need and are working on it.

Can I ask you why you have this requirement to run Java on Phusion Passenger? Would love to see how else we can help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick response. Since you asked,  I am going to use **Amazon Linux** for my web app deployment which is developed primarily in Java. I thought of using Phusion Passenger server is a best option compared to Tomcat.